# Issues with JButtons and ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionevent

For some reason, when I click my buttons, it makes it into the actionPerformed method, but the program can't match any of the buttons to an actionevent, so nothing works when any of my buttons are pressed.  I took the code out of paintcomponent and put it in the constructor, but now the buttons don't show up.  Can someone please help?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

//

public class game extends JFrame//header
{
        private CardPanel mp;
        private Font big = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 100);
        private Font small = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 90);
        private Font norm = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 23);
        private CardLayout cards;
        private JButton back;
        private boolean clairewang=false;
        private boolean wangfam=false;
        private boolean cl=false;
        private JButton next;
        private JButton instruction;
        private JButton startb;
         private JButton done;
        private JTextArea title;
        private Color c=new Color(186,225,200);
        private int a=0;;
        private JButton yes;
        private JButton no;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private JButton claire= new JButton("PLAY!");
        private JButton fambam=new JButton("PLAY!");
        private JButton sickbob=new JButton("PLAY!");
        private String pc="Play as Claire (medium)- an able bodied 20 yearold";
        private String pfb="Play as a family (hard)- receive more waterper week.";
        private String psb="Play as Bob (easy)- he is connected to thecity's water" ;
       private String psb2="supply because he has brain cancer.";



        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                game b = new game();//create constructor
        }
        public game()//Bio constructor
        {
           //set everything for JFrame
           setSize(900,600);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           setLocation(0,0);
           setResizable(false);//set to false
           mp = new CardPanel();
           cards = new CardLayout();
           back = new JButton("BACK");
           done= new JButton("DONE");

          next = new JButton("NEXT");
                                                next.setBounds(275,200, 315, 220);


           Start beg = new Start();

           instruct1 inst1 = new instruct1();
           instruct2 inst2 = new instruct2();
           choosepanel ch = new choosepanel();
           sb1 sb= new sb1();
           fb1 f1= new fb1();//FINISH THIS
           fb2 f2= new fb2();
           fb3 f3= new fb3();
           fb4 f4= new fb4();
           c1 s= new c1();

           mp.setLayout(cards);
           mp.add(beg,"start");

           mp.add(inst1,"i1");
           mp.add(inst2, "i2");
           mp.add(ch,"choose");
                        mp.add(s, "c1");
                        mp.add(sb, "sb");
                        mp.add(f1, "fb1");
                        mp.add(f2, "fb2");
                        mp.add(f3, "fb3");
                        mp.add(f4, "fb4");
           setContentPane(mp);
           setVisible(true);
        }

        class CardPanel extends JPanel
        {
                public CardPanel()
                {
                }
        }
        class Start extends JPanel implements ActionListener
        {

                public Start()
                {
                    setLayout(null);

                    startb = new JButton("START");
                    startb.setBounds(255,200, 315, 100);

                    instruction = new JButton("INSTRUCTIONS");
                    instruction.setBounds(255,320, 315, 100);


                                                //make text area uneditable
                     instruction.addActionListener(this);
                    startb.addActionListener(this);
                     add(startb);
                    add(instruction);
                }
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
                {
                       setBackground(c);
                                                super.paintComponent(g); //import image
                                                setFont(big);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("THIRST", 230,150);
                                        //      g.setColor(c);
                                        //      g.drawString("THIRST",235,153);
                                        //      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);//have loop that draws waves

                                for( y=0;y<600;y+=200){
                                        for(x=0;x<800;x+=100){
                                                g.drawArc(x,y, 100,50,0,-180);
                                                }
                                }
                                        for(y=100;y<600;y+=200){
                                        for(x=-50;x<800;x+=100){
                                                g.drawArc(x,y, 100,50,0,-180);
                                                }
                                        }


                                //for( y=0; y<600;x+=100){
                                //              for(x=0; x<800;x+=50){
                                        //                      g.drawArc(x, y, 50,50,0,-180);
                                        //      }
                                //}

                }

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                                         if (evt.getSource()==instruction) {
                                                         cards.show(mp,"i1"); }
                                        else if(evt.getSource()==startb){
                                                cards.show(mp, "choose");
                                        }

                }
        }
       /* class instruct extends JPanel implements ActionListener
        {//header

                public instruct()
                {
                                                setLayout(null);


                                                next = new JButton("NEXT");
                                                next.setBounds(600,500,100,50);
                                                //instruction.setBounds(225,500, 275, 575);
                        back = new JButton("BACK");
                                                back.setBounds(100,500,100,50);
                     //   instruction.setBounds(225,500, 375, 575);
                      next.addActionListener(this);
                      back.addActionListener(this);
                                                add(next);

                        add(back);


                }
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        setBackground(c);
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        setFont(big);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("THING0", 230,150);

                        //draw the instructions in the center using blackor white

                }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

                       //  if(((JButton)(evt.getSource()).getText()).equals("BACK"))

                                                //       cards.show(mp,"start");
                                                //       System.out.println("X");
                                                //       }
                                                //if ((((JButton)(evt.getSource()).getText()).equals("NEXT")) ){
                                                         //cards.show(mp,"i1");
                                                         //System.out.println("X");
                                                        //}

                                                        if (evt.getSource()==next ){
                                                         cards.show(mp,"i1");
                                                         System.out.println("X");
                                                        }
                                                        else if (evt.getSource()==back) {
                                                 cards.show(mp,"start");
                                                         System.out.println("X");
                                                         }



                }

                        } */

                        class instruct1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
                                public instruct1(){
                                        setLayout(null);
                                                next = new JButton("NEXT");
                                                next.setBounds(600,500,100,50);
                                                //instruction.setBounds(225,500, 275, 575);
                        back = new JButton("BACK");
                                                back.setBounds(100,500,100,50);
                                                next.addActionListener(this);
                                                back.addActionListener(this);
                                                add(next);
                                                add(back);
                                        }
                                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                                                setBackground(c);
                                                super.paintComponent(g); //import image
                                                setFont(big);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("THING1", 230,150);
                                        }
                                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                         if (evt.getSource()==back) {
                                                         cards.show(mp,"start"); }
                                                else if(evt.getSource()==next){
                                                         cards.show(mp,"i2");
                                                        }

        }

                                }
                        class instruct2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
                                public instruct2(){
                                setLayout(null);


                                                done = new JButton("DONE");
                                                back = new JButton("BACK");

                                                back.addActionListener(this);
                                                done.addActionListener(this);

                                                done.setBounds(600,500,100,50);
                                                //instruction.setBounds(225,500, 275, 575);

                                                back.setBounds(100,500,100,50);
                                                add(done);
                                                add(back);

                                        }
                                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

                                                setBackground(c);
                                                super.paintComponent(g); //import image
                                                setFont(big);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("THING2", 230,150);
                                        }
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                                             if (evt.getSource()==back) {
                                                cards.show(mp,"i1"); }
                                                else if(evt.getSource()==done){
                                                 cards.show(mp,"start");
                                                        }

        }
        }

       class choosepanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
                        public choosepanel(){
                                setLayout(null);
                                sickbob.addActionListener(this);
                                fambam.addActionListener(this);
                                claire.addActionListener(this);
                                sickbob.setBounds(600,200,100,50);
                                claire.setBounds(600,300,100,50);
                                fambam.setBounds(600,400,100,50);
                                add(sickbob);
                                add(claire);
                                add(fambam);

                                                //instruction.setBounds(225,500, 275, 575);

                        }
                        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                                setBackground(c);
                                super.paintComponent(g);
                        setFont(small);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("CHOOSE PLAYER", 0,150);
                                g.setFont(norm);
                                g.drawString(psb,50,225);
                                g.drawString(psb2,50,250);
                                g.drawString(pc,50,325);
                                g.drawString(pfb,50,425);

                        }
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                        if(evt.getSource()==claire){
                                cards.show(mp, "c1");
                                clairewang=true;
                            }

                        else if(evt.getSource()==sickbob){
                                cards.show(mp, "c1");
                                cl=true;}
                        else if(evt.getSource()==fambam){
                                cards.show(mp, "c1");
                                wangfam=true;
                        }

                        }
                      /*  public boolean stuff(){
                            if(wangfam) return wangfam;
                            else if(cl)return cl;
                            else if(clairewang)return clairewang;
                        } */


        }
        class c1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
                public void c1(){
                    /* setLayout(null);
                    next=new JButton("NEXT");
                    no=new JButton("NO");
                    yes=new JButton("YES");
                     yes.addActionListener(this);
                     no.addActionListener(this);
                    next.addActionListener(this);
                    yes.setBounds(100,200,100,50);
                    no.setBounds(300,300,100,50);
                    next.setBounds(700,400,100,50);
                    add(yes);
                    add(no);
                    add(next); */
                     next=new JButton("NEXT");
                    no=new JButton("NO");
                    yes=new JButton("YES");
                     yes.addActionListener(this);
                     no.addActionListener(this);
                    next.addActionListener(this);
                    yes.setBounds(100,200,100,50);
                    no.setBounds(300,200,100,50);
                    next.setBounds(700,500,100,50);
                    add(yes);
                    add(no);
                    add(next);


                }
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        setBackground(c);
                                super.paintComponent(g);
                                setLayout(null);

                        setFont(norm);
                                                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                g.drawString("Your flowers are wilting. Water your lawn?",20,100);
                                                //print situation yn
                                                //jbutton yes and j button no

                                        g.fillRect(700, 75, 100, 400);//draw the bar that shows how much wateris left
                                        g.fillArc(700,65,100,20,0,180);
                                        g.fillArc(700,465,100,20,0,-180);
                                        g.setColor(c);
                                        g.fillRect(705,82, 90,390);
                                        g.fillArc(705, 463, 90, 18, 0 , -180);
                                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                        g.fillRect(705,82, 90,a);
                                       // if(clairewang)System.out.println(a);
                                         if(wangfam)System.out.println("wangfam");
                                        else if(cl)System.out.println("cl");



                }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                    System.out.println("stuff");
                        if(evt.getSource()==yes){
                                if(clairewang){
                                    a=15;
                                    System.out.println(a);}
                                else if(wangfam)a+=20;
                                else if(cl)a+=10;
                                //clairewang=true;
                                repaint();

                            }

                        else if(evt.getSource()==next){
                                cards.show(mp, "sb");
                               // cl=true;}

                        //yes gives an int a value
                        //no stays 0
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Where you declare your buttons?

Comment: Between the largest class and main.  I don't think that's the problem, as the buttons on other panels are working fine.  Thank you though!

Comment: can you add a minimal runable example?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question.  Sorry, I'm fairly new.  The project is kind of due really soon so I don't have time to change the layouts, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, @Jens, I just added it.

Comment: *"I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question."*  In that case, I might even consider future questions carefully, and frame an answer.  Of course, you can [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30252596/418556) any time you like.  (And it has already attracted 2 close votes that boil down to 'lack of an MCVE'..)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted some code to make it shorter.  If anybody can fix my issue with the buttons that don't show up, I'd really really appreciate it. :^)

Answer (score 1):

Move the creation and init code out of paintComponent() into constructor

The code

```
            next=new JButton("NEXT");
            no=new JButton("NO");
            yes=new JButton("YES");
             yes.addActionListener(this);
             no.addActionListener(this);
            next.addActionListener(this);
            yes.setBounds(100,200,100,50);
            no.setBounds(300,200,100,50);
            next.setBounds(700,500,100,50);
            add(yes);
            add(no);
            add(next);
```

In fact on each repaint it recreates the buttons and readd them. Thus in actionPerformed() button state is changed (to show pressed state) and the button is recreated. And of course it != clicked one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but for some reason now the buttons don't show up for some reason. Do you have any idea why?  Thanks!

Comment: I have many ideas:-) the general idea it's something wrong in the code you haven't posted. Another good idea would be to choose LayoutManager rather than null layout and setBounds()

Comment: Thanks, I'll post the entire code.  Also, this is for a game that I'm making for my class and I really didn't like the look of any of the LayoutManagers so I just made my own.

Comment: *"Move the creation and init code out of paintComponent() into constructor"*  That code (the `setBounds(..)` part) should be moved to the garbage bin.  *"Thanks, I'll post the entire code"*  No! Make a *minimal* example.  If it is related to buttons, have 2 instead of ..however many this example has.  If you can get it working for two buttons, the solution for 10 or more will likely be obvious.  But start with just 1 or 2.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that part, now the buttons just don't show up :,(